# CEO or Managing Director

Tags: differences

For a small consulting firm, is it appropriate to use CEO or Managing Director as the owner of the business?

Comment: How about **"Owner"**?  Otherwise, you can give yourself any title you like, even "God-Emperor"

Comment: Yes, it is appropriate, if the owner is indeed performing those roles.

Comment: Many years ago, I conducted hundreds of interviews for the British Annual Labour Force Survey and Continuous Labour Force Survey. I was struck by the remarkably large proportion of people employing only themselves or less than half a dozen others who grandly proclaimed their job title as 'Managing Director' rather than the more mundane-sounding 'Owner' or 'Proprietor'.

Comment: If you want to give a title to the person who makes the important decisions and is responsible for running the business, then Managing Director would be appropriate. When I ran a small consultancy as a Limited Company in the UK, regulations stated that there must be a Managing director and a Company Secretary. The owner is not necessarily the MD. CEO implies that there are several levels of management, which is less likely to occur in a small company.